# Why does this unit test pass in Visual Studio 2005 but fail in VS2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(FormatException))]
public void PassGodammit()
{
    throw new FormatException();
}
```

?? driving me mad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure to check your project references after you upgrade from 2005 to 2008: for some odd reason the Upgrade Wizard does not upgrade references to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework` and leaves references to version 8.0 of this assembly. Just manually add a reference to v 9.0 of this assembly.

Answer (score 1):

I just copied your code to my VS2008. It gets a "Passed" as a result.
Do you have any other info? It works well for me.